# Python socket, send an int, which informs the client about the length of the following data

Tags: python, sockets, serialization

I have a server, which listens for connections on a socket and once the client connects a dictionary of varying size is sent.

To inform the client, how many bytes it should receive, I want to send the size of the dictionary first.

```
dic={'asdf':'1234', 'ghkj':'5678'}
serialized_dict = pickle.dumps(dic)
dic_size = sys.getsizeof(serialized_dict)

connection.send(dic_size)

connection.send(serialized_dict)
```

This is roughly what the server does once the client connects.

Now, I can't send the `dic_size` as an integer, which means I probably have to serialize it as well. If I do so, how can I read the correct number of bytes on the client, to receive the integer value, and then receive as many bytes as the integer value says?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it like this. The general way to alert a socket buffer of the end of a stream is to send a delimiter/end marker of some sort after the dictionary and have the client look for the end marker. Once the end marker is received they know they have received the end of the dictionary.

I believe in SMTP mail servers to denote the end of a field they use something like `\r\n`

```
self.messBuffer = "" #message buffer
while self.messBuffer.find("\r\n") == -1:
            try:
                #take in 500 bytes
                self.socket.settimeout(10) #set timeout of socket 
                self.messBuffer += self.socket.recv(500)
                self.socket.settimeout(None)
            #if there is a socket error
            except socket.error:
                self.socket.close() #close the socket
                return
        #find the end of the message which is marked by "\r\n"
        end = self.messBuffer.find("\r\n")

        #get the message which is 0 to the end(occurrence of "\r\n")
        msg = self.messBuffer[0:end]
        #reset the message buffer to what is behind "\r\n"
        self.messBuffer = self.messBuffer[end+2:]
        return msg
```

Comment: Don't I need to know the length on the client side for the pickle deserialisation? I mean I need to know when the serialised data has been completely sent, so I can assign the socket.recv(lenght)) to a variable and deserialise it. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @boolean.is.null I updated my answer, I pulled some code I worked on from an SMTP mail server I made for class. Not all the code is necessary but it's the basic concept. You just keep receiving bytes till you get the delimiter. The code pretty much explains it all

Comment: Thank you. I understand the approach there, but I believe that's not applicable in my scenario, as the data is serialized and not searchable until it's deserialized.

Comment: The serialized data is a string is it not? I don't see why you can't just add the delimiter to the end and use my approach above. @boolean.is.null I just checked locally and the type returned by `pickle.dumps(dic)` is a string. So my approach should work fine

Comment: The result of the `pickle.dumps(thiswasreceived)` is a string, yes. But I can't deserialize the received data until I'm sure I received the complete data.

Comment: yeah so just add a delimiter like I showed you above. It must be something not in the serialized data. Then once you have received the delimiter. You know you have received all the serialized data. Now deserialize all the data you have received before the delimiter @boolean.is.null exactly how I did in my code. I just didn't deserialize anything because i didn't need to. Looking at my code all you need to do is deserialize msg before returning essentially

Comment: I need to cast the received data to string, which would work, but I don't know how I can send the delimiter as a string, as that doesn't work for sending. E.g. `connection.send('\r\n\')` results in `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120172/discussion-between-james-russo-and-boolean-is-null).